# Using Raw MapView to Float Buttons

Tags: android, android-button, google-maps-android-api-2

Before the new google maps api came out i was able to implement a google map fragment and i would add buttons to float over the map by adding them to the xml file. I am able to use this same technique in the xml file of the Raw map view Demo activity. The demo activity is a fragment activity but if feel like it fails to actually use a fragment. It just fills its view with the map from an xml file.

Is it possible to force a map fragment to load a specific layout without creating a fragment that extends mapfragment and having to deal with the mapview lifecycles yourself. I know that doing so is not usually recommended.

Old XML for Buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="0xR1g8qRRLoUp8-8gd7050zKWtMQCMDDHhizisw"
    android:clickable="true" >

    android:apiKey = "APIKEY" >
</com.google.android.maps.MapView>

<ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/zoom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button" >
```

XML from rawMapViewDemo

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cacbutton"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/taxi" >
</ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to build my map fragment programatically which does not allow me to do what i want to do. Adding the fragments to the layout file does allow me to add the buttons correctly. Now there is just the issue of showing and hiding a mapfragment and the view not being updated. 
The XML below is what worked for me. Note that i am actually using 2 map fragments. i have not figured out how to use one button for both fragments yet. I am open to ideas.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cacbutton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button" >
        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cacbutton2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button" >
        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```